# Use object that is being initialized as parameter

Tags: c#, circular-reference, object-initializers

I stumbled upon the problem of not being able to use a windows method as a property inside the objects initializer:

```
  var window = new DialogWindow
  {
    DataContext = new YesNoDialogViewModel()
    {
      DialogMessage = confirmation.Content as string,
      DialogTitle = confirmation.Title,
    }
  };

  (window.DataContext as YesNoDialogViewModel).CloseWindowCommand = new ActionCommand(window.Close);
```

I wan't to do something like this:

```
var window = new DialogWindow
  {
    DataContext = new YesNoDialogViewModel()
    {
      DialogMessage = confirmation.Content as string,
      DialogTitle = confirmation.Title,
      CloseWindowCommand = new ActionCommand(window.Close)
    }
  };
```

However, i can't seem to figure it out (`new ActionCommand(window.Close)` doesnt compile, cannot use window before its declared).

Is there any hack or workaround to just add the reference to the void anyways?

Comment: @MatteoUmili yes, I figured. Thank you for the link. It's not possible apparently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put it in object initializer because `ActionCommand()` uses in argument the object which is not created yet - window -> `window.Close()`.